# How to connect to WMS server with HTTP Refer parameter

Tags: qgis, wms

I want to use some layer from WMS server that use `HTTP Referer header` in QGIS (3.22.3-Białowieża).
Here is a original URL to wms server responce:

```
https://maps.roslesinforg.ru/proxy/service?&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=shape_forestries&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=6261721.357121639,7827151.696402045,6574807.424977722,8140237.764258131
```

and `Referer header`

```
https://maps.roslesinforg.ru/
```

So i created a new WMS connection with parameters:
Server URL - https://maps.roslesinforg.ru/proxy/service
Referer - https://maps.roslesinforg.ru/

And this allows me to recive Capabilities. But if I add layer to the map I don't get any images.
I the same time I can get image if send request from `postman`:

[image]

How can I get this layer in QGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `referer` parameter in the `Create a New WMS/WMTS Connection` dialog.

[image: preview]

**EDIT:**
But it looks like the capabilities document returned points to a mapproxy and not to the endpoint you want to reach:
[image: endpoint] So using WMS in QGIS always queries the capabilities document first. This one is not the one you would like to use. You could download the `XML` Capabilties and replace the wrong parts. Something like [this](https://pastebin.com/k5KdXfb5). You would need to host it on some local webserver and point the url to it. Works fine for me:

[image: ru]

**EDIT2:**
As mentioned by Ian Turton in the comments the easist way is to check the flag `"Ignore GetMap/GetTile/GetLegendGraphic URI reported in capabilities"`. So no need for a custom XML.

Comment: I think simply checking the `ignore GetMap ... URL in capabilities` box should fix that

Comment: @bloigge I just checked Qgis log and found that layer's url replaced with mapproxy address. So i check option from Ian comment and i get my layer! But on low levels i get black tiles only. Looks strange because on https://maps.roslesinforg.ru/ webmap everything fine.

Comment: @IanTurton - didn't know about that flag. updated my answer.

Comment: @KliverMax - guess that is a different issue.